# Ajax - understanding of the code

Tags: ajax

I try to  understand Ajax. I'd like to understand how the data and commands flow in the code. I have the following code. Please, read my comments in this code. The comments describe, how I understand the code. The problem is marked as PROBLEM!!! Important notice: The code is working, I only try to understand the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META charset="UTF-8" />
        <TITLE>Test02</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <p id="demo">Let AJAX change this text.</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
        <SCRIPT>
            function loadDoc() {
                // select right object
                function createXhttp(){
                    var variable;
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for modern browsers
                        variable = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        variable = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }

                    return variable;
                }


                var xhttp = createXhttp();
                // check the state
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
                    // if the response is ready and file or url exists
                    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                        /* display the text in console - but which text if xttp.open
                        with source file is opened on the next line? (PROBLEM!!!)*/
                        console.log(xhttp.responseText);
                    }
                };
                // use method get and load the content of ajax_info.txt
                xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
                // send the request above
                xhttp.send();
            }
        </SCRIPT>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: `// code for IE6, IE5` — Why are you supporting those browsers?

Comment: @Quentin Because that was shown in tutorial by W3school. It is useful for users with older versions of IE. Do you think I should delete it?

Comment: What users with older versions of IE? :)

Comment: @Quentin If I want to be sarcastic I will write: What users with IE? :) I heard good joke on this topic. Browser IE is only good to download other browser. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but which text if xttp.open with source file is opened on the next line?

Let's take another example.

```
document.getElementById('some_button').onclick = function () {
    console.log(document.getElementById("some_text_box").value);
}
```

It doesn't matter if the user hasn't typed anything in *some_text_box* at this point, because the function won't run until *some_button* is clicked.

Now back to XHR:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }
};
```

… it doesn't matter that the request hasn't been sent **yet**, because the function won't run until the response arrives.

(OK, it will run every time the ready state changes, but the `if` statement means the meat of it won't run until the response arrives).

Comment: Thank you. That helped me a lot.